# Enabling Android A2DP SINK and RFCOMM simultaneous traffic (Lollipop)

Tags: bluetooth, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth, spp, a2dp

**Background:**

I’m looking to enable A2DP audio streaming SINK support on my Nexus 4 & 5 devices (running Lollipop) . I also need concurrent SPP/RFCOMM bidirectional traffic for my application command and control. I’ll be sending serial traffic to a microcontroller via a Bluetooth module (such as the [BlueGiga WT32i](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/wt32i-bluetooth-audio-module/) or ) which will be controlling various other hardware. As such, I believe AVRCP isn’t up to the task.

**Question:**

Has anyone enabled A2DP SINK support in Android (Target Lollipop or earlier) and either successfully got an concurrent SPP/RFCOMM channel working OR can offer options on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For A2DP Sink support -
Yes. It is possible. I have done it in Android JB.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892944/987500 - Please read my reply.

Comment: Could you please help me to send AVRCP/A2DP commands through coding to another device.