# Android 5.0 Bluetooth A2DP Sink

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

*I have a very specific answer for which I am looking. I hope that there is someone out there that is smart enough as to point me in the correct direction.*

**Background:** I have an Android phone (LG Power on 5.0 *rooted*) as well as a Nexus 10 running 6.0. In my house I have set up a very nice PA system to which I would love to stream audio. I am fully capable of plugging in a 3.5mm cord to listen to audio or to stream audio over WiFi.

However, I am a stubborn person and have always fancied the idea of streaming audio from one device to another via bluetooth. After all, Android is Linux.

After searching on the Internet, quite extensively, there seem to be MANY people who would love to find a solution. There are answers ranging from:

*'This cannot be done',*

*'Why would you ever want to do that?'* 
to

*'Here are all the things to may need. Build away. Oh and by the way, there may be more that you need'*

I do not find these answers satisfactory and would like to put out there a request to all of higher intelligence than myself to find an easy (not requiring building a custom ROM, modifying the kernel, making my own application etc) way to achieve this goal.

Here is one source that seems to be very close to the answer:
[Android device as a receiver for A2DP profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile/31458979#31458979)

**If any  more info is needed, PLEASE ASK!**

Thanks in advance for all of the hard work and effort that is put forth on this site. I am truly thankful for all of the people willing to set aside time to help myself, an invalid when it comes to the intricacies of Android.