# How to set android as Bluetooth Sink to act like a Bluetooth earphones

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth, a2dp, bluetooth-profile

I'm working on a Android app which needs to work with similar functionalities of Bluetooth earphones. i.e., when I connect the mobile (in which my app installed) to other bluetooth devices like pc or another mobile, i need to set the moble as a receiver and want to play audio of those source devices in this mobile speaker. As of my research to achieve this functionality, I need to set the bluetooth in mobile as sink (receiver).

But I found no way to achieve this directly in Android, but we can use some reflections to make this possible.

here are some of the resources that I referred.

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/refs/heads/main/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dpsink/A2dpSinkService.java
- [Android device as a receiver for A2DP profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile)
- [Android 5.0 Bluetooth A2DP Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624595/android-5-0-bluetooth-a2dp-sink)
- [How To Modify Android's Bluetooth Stack to Enable A2dp Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104611/how-to-modify-androids-bluetooth-stack-to-enable-a2dp-sink)

any help/suggesions would greatly appreciated.