# Where to find Bluedroid config files on Android 5.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, a2dp, sink

I want to use a Lenovo Tab2 A7 (Android 5.0, rooted) as a A2DP sink. To do this, i have to edit the files: 
/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/include/bt_target.h
and
/packages/apps/Bluetooth/res/values/config.xml

But i cant find them. I searched in every folder on the tablet. I also searched on the source which is provided by Lenovo:
http://support.lenovo.com/de/de/products/tablets/a-series/a7-10-2/downloads/ds105762

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files **bt_target.h** and **config.xml** actually do not exist on android device. These files are present in AOSP code. To enable A2DP sink you have to actually dig into the code, go to these files location as mentioned by you, make the changes and then compile either complete image or just bluedroid.

Also your device should be rooted if you just want to replace bluedroid library. In case of complete image, anyway you have to flash your complete image.

But, **unfortunately** it's not yet done for A2DP sink. With above steps you'll be able to enable sink profile and connect to it and start streaming from remote device to your device but the streaming data could not be played on your device. Reason being, AOSP does not have that portion of code available as of now which could play the streaming data on your phone speaker.

Refer below link for more info

[A2DP sink discussion on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile)

But wait, there is one good news, with limitation though, **Samsung Galaxy S7** and above series phones do support sink role. But right now there seems to be limitation in sink functionality of the phone. Galaxy S7 and above series phones can only connect with **Tizen Smart TVs** at present through in built quickconnect app.