# Finding directory locations in Android

Tags: android, directory, directory-structure

I have an Android question:
When someone links to a file directory, where am I supposed to look?

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile) it is suggested to make some changes in the A2DP Bluetooth profile
in `/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/include/bt_target.h`.

Where is this `/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/include/bt_target.h`?

Is it on my device? On the PC?

Is it under the Android program files? 
(`C:\Program Files\Android`)

Or the Android Studio projects file? (`C:\Users\someUser\AndroidStudioProjects`)

Help appreciated

// David

Comment: When someone links to a file directory, there is no single answer as to where that is located, so your question does not really make sense. It should be clear from the path itself or from the context in in case. From the context of the linked question it would appear the file is a part of the [Android OS source code](https://source.android.com/devices/halref/bt__target_8h_source.html).

Comment: "it would appear the file is a part of the Android OS source code", then I am not sure how to phrase the question. The link just goes off to a website with a bunch of code - how is the code you linked related to either the Android device or my computer?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/halref/bt__target_8h_source.html

Where is this, other than on the website?

Comment: You download the Android OS source code from that site. You make that change in that file. You [compile the OS](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) from the modified sources and flash your device with it.

Comment: If this question relates to Bluedroid (bluetooth stack in Android) then you can get some good info from this place: http://mre4less.com/blog/category/technology/bluedroid/ . You could learn to setup bluedroid code at your sytem from this link. The current path for bluedroid in aosp is:https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt

Comment: Thank you @aksonlyaks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You download the Android OS source code from that site. You make that change in that file. You compile the OS from the modified sources and flash your device with it" – GSerg