# How to enable android bluetooth a2dp sink and play music on android L

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

we recently work on a audio box which based on Android, as a audio box must act to a reciver with bluetooth(while a2dp sink profile in bluetooth can do this), but we have do many works over weeks on it , but it still not work, so i'd like to ask somebody who know or had similar expirence on it could help.

our works :

1、packages/apps/Bluetooth/res/values/config.xml

```
<bool name="profile_supported_a2dp_sink">true</bool>
<bool name="profile_supported_hfpclient">true</bool>
```

2、external/bluetooth/bluedroid/include/bt_target.h

```
#define BTA_AV_SINK_INCLUDED TRUE
```

after these bluetooth seems to worked , i can user a phone link to these box and i can play music with a player through bluetooth , and also i can see the data packages in the box by tcpdump, but there is no sound , we also find some other informations :

[Android device as a receiver for A2DP profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile/31458979#31458979)

but it seems didn't work.

so anybody could help.

thanks a lot

Comment: Try to apply [this patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/98161/) to source  code.

Comment: Hi conggang, You got any solution??if you got then please share with us?