# Unable to receive BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED broadcast

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-source, a2dp

*Background :*

Developing application to make android phone A2DP receiver.

BlueDroid stack supports A2DP sink, but it's disabled by default. 
  [Modified source code to enable A2DP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763756/android-device-as-a-receiver-for-a2dp-profile). Android phone is seen as HeadsFree Device and is connectable.

*Problem :*

**I can't hear sound.**

*Tried :*

[A2dpSinkStateMachine](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java) class is in charge of acting android as `A2dpSink`. One of the state is [Connected](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#473), it has method [broadcastAudioState](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#695), which is called when audio starts/stops streaming. ([line 579](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#579))

`broadcastAudioState` sends broadcast with action `BluetoothA2dpSink.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED` ([line 696](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#701)) and writes log [*`A2DP Playing state....`*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#703)))

Registered broadcast receiver

*- tried via `manifest.xml` file*

```
<receiver android:name=".PlayingStateChangeBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*- dynamically too*

```
Intent intent = 
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED));
```

*- dynamically with permission*

```
  Intent intent = 
       registerReceiver(
             mReceiver, 
             new IntentFilter(BluetoothA2dp.ACTION_PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED), 
            "android.permission.BLUETOOTH", 
             new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
```

`onReceive` method is never called.

Additionally:

- while registering dynamically `registerReceiver` returns `null`.
- inside `Android monitor` window, i see log *[A2DP Playing state ...](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.1.1_r14/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpSinkStateMachine.java#703)*, meaning broadcast is sent.
- `android.bluetooth.a2dp-sink.profile.action.PLAYING_STATE_CHANGED` is declared as `<protected-broadcast>` in [platform/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r14/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#146) file

Any ideas, how to fix that ?

*Thanks*

Comment: I am sorry to ask this, but did you make sure your app has BLUETOOTH permission in the manifest?
It's a system exported broadcast so there should not be any further problem.

Comment: @Olaia Yes, app has `BLUETOOTH` permission but with no luck